# remember selected cells in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create to store the selected cells in array and then when u then press on the backbutton and go back to this viewcontroller it should remember the selected cells. The indexPaths is saved correctly in the singleton classes, but it does not seem like the [pickedArray containsObject:indexPath] is being triggered? what am i doing wrong?

could it be because the NSIndexPath number is not equal? if yes how can i fix this?

## rentType.h NSObject

```
@interface rentType : NSObject


@property BOOL picked;

@end
```

## viewDidLoad

```
 menuArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Under 12 måneder", @"Over 12 måneder", @"Ubegrænset", nil];
```

## tableView Methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.137 green: 0.145 blue: 0.157 alpha: 1];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 14];



    obj = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];

    if (obj.picked) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (obj.picked) {
        obj.picked = NO;
    } else {
        obj.picked = YES;
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be a better approach to have a `picked` property inside each of the objects that you're storing in `menuArray`.  That way, each object could tell you whether it was picked without having to juggle a second array that has a chance of becoming out-of-phase with the one that's being used for the cell content.

The idea is to set up your objects that match the cells so that they are not strings, but custom objects.  Then you can get rid of `pickedArray` and write:

```
   CustomObject *obj = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = obj.text;

    if (obj.picked) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

Comment: could u make a small snippet, i'm not sure i'm getting the approach u think is the best?

Comment: @FrederikHagelund He's saying at a "picked" boolean to the object type you're storing, and when you press the back button, just check to see what objects are picked (picked = TRUE).

Comment: i've updated question and tried to do what u said, but it seem to give this error:  unrecognized selector sent to instance . What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How/where do you define what kind of thing `obj` is?  (Presumably, it should be a `rentType` according to your new code.  Is that what you're putting into the array?)

Comment: @FrederikHagelund The thing you are doing wrong in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is that you are not retrieving obj from data array. You must get object at index indexPath.row from your data array then set it's picked property.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just one line of code:

```
 tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```